# Shortcode from a function not working

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode from a custom function in WP but it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

I have a function in child's theme function.php and add_shortcode code:

```
function uniquetestfunction() {
echo '<div class="my_class">Test Element</div>';
}
add_shortcode(‘uniqueshortcodename’,’uniquetestfunction’);
```

Which should generate a shortcode [uniqueshortcodename]. I have done this with existing functions in different plugins and it worked fine.

But when added to a page, it's not rendering the function, just showing the shortcode as a text. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm very new to PHP :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) for add_shortcode, you need your function to return the content:

```
function uniquetestfunction($attributes) {
   return '<div class="my_class">Test Element</div>';
}
add_shortcode('uniqueshortcodename','uniquetestfunction');
```

You also used the wrong quotes in your add_shortcode line - stick with single `'` or double `"` quotes.

Comment: It seems to be working with echo as well. I have changed the quotes, I guess that was the issue! Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Glad it's sorted, either way. Welcome to the site as well.